# How can i make boxes with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i make boxes with bootstrap like as this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWxxb.png)

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="text">
        <div class="heading h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor  <br>
sit<br>
amet </p>
        <a href="">
            Lorem ipsum            <i class="mdi mdi-box-right"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Either make use of Bootstrap's [**grid layout**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and set a custom `height`, or use Bootstrap's [**cards**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/). As it stands, your question shows little effort, and is rather broad.

Comment: As i tagged it's for Bootstrap 3, Cards is only for Bootstrap 4

Comment: Is the provided answer correct? @Efex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.box {
  background: #998b00;
  color: white;
  width: 450px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 180px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  justify-content: center
}

.box .text {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.text .heading {
  max-width: 300px;
  font-size: 27px;
}

.text p {
  color: #cfca8a;
}

.text a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="heading h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor <br> sit
            <br> amet </p>
          <a href="">
            Lorem ipsum            <i class="mdi mdi-box-right"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="heading h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor <br> sit
            <br> amet </p>
          <a href="">
            Lorem ipsum            <i class="mdi mdi-box-right"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="heading h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor <br> sit
            <br> amet </p>
          <a href="">
            Lorem ipsum            <i class="mdi mdi-box-right"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="heading h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor <br> sit
            <br> amet </p>
          <a href="">
            Lorem ipsum            <i class="mdi mdi-box-right"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="heading h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor <br> sit
            <br> amet </p>
          <a href="">
            Lorem ipsum            <i class="mdi mdi-box-right"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="heading h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor <br> sit
            <br> amet </p>
          <a href="">
            Lorem ipsum            <i class="mdi mdi-box-right"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```